# how do i create a dataframe that matches these two together

Tags: python, pandas

```
A = [[1, 4, 15, 12, 42, 56, 71, 94, 50,],
[-5, 82, 93, -54, 85, 96, -57, 88, 99],
[21, 32, 43, -51, 8, 92, -53, 84, 95],
[5, 9, 10, -59, 88, 97, -56, 85, 94],
[6, 9, 6, -54, 83, 92, -51, 89, 98],
[12, 5, 19, -59, 82, 91, -55, 68, 29]]


names = [_ for _ in 'lmnopqrst']
df = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=names)


d = ['l', 'm', 'n']
f = ['o', 'p', 'q']
g = ['r', 's', 't']

dff = []
for i in list(d):
    for j in list(f):
        for k in list(g):
           dff.append((i,j,k))
dff = pd.DataFrame(dff)
```

i have a dataframe with multiple different combinations of the letters but i want to create dataframes of each row of dff using the columns of df as values but i dont wnat to run them manually is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: Publish the expected result to facilitate the visualization of the case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.